# About JavaScript and PHP assignment operators: Why the different results?

Tags: javascript, php

JavaScript code:

```
var a = 1, b = 2;
a = b + (b = a) * 0;
// result a = 2, b = 1;
```

PHP code 1:

```
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
$a = $b + ($b = $a) * 0;
// result $a = 1, $b = 1;
```

PHP code 2:

```
$a = 1;
$b = 2;
$a = (int)$b + ($b = $a) * 0;
// result $a = 2, $b = 1;
```

What causes the difference between PHP and JavaScript assignment operators?

Is it operator precedence related?

**I want to know what the reasons are. Thanks!**

Comment: I suspect that neither language defines what happens if you assign to a variable and use it in the same expression. But if they do, then the difference is in order of operations.

Comment: Why are you writing such contorted code in the first place? There's no excuse for mixing assignment into the expression like this.

Comment: $a = 1;
$b = 2;
$a = $b + (($b = $a) * 0);

Comment: I don't think this is a _real life_ programming issue. Voting to close. It would be best on programmers.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, operator precedence doesn't factor into evaluation order, therefore using assignments in complex evaluations reusing the result of the evaluation is always undefined.

[From the PHP manual](http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php):

> Operator precedence and associativity only determine how expressions
>   are grouped, they do not specify an order of evaluation. PHP does not
>   (in the general case) specify in which order an expression is
>   evaluated and **code that assumes a specific order of evaluation should
>   be avoided**, because the behavior can change between versions of PHP or
>   depending on the surrounding code.

In short, the output of `$b + ($b = $a)` is undefined, since the grouping overrides precedence, and does not in anyway enforce whether the assignment occurs before fetching the left operand of the addition or after. The *precedence* is well defined, the execution/evaluation order is *not*.

Comment: this is why we can't have anything nice in this life!!!!, How it's possible that PHP doesn't waranty an execution order. now offcially hate PHP a little more.!

Comment: Thank you for your enthusiastic response

Answer (score 1):

To augment @NielsKeurentjes' answer with JavaScript's point of view:

(In contrast to PHP) JavaScript specifies the order of operations (operands are evaluated left-to-right), which makes it work as expected.

[From the ECMAScript specification](http://es5.github.io/#x11.6.1):

> The production `AdditiveExpression : AdditiveExpression + MultiplicativeExpression` is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let `lref` be the result of evaluating `AdditiveExpression`.
> 2. Let `lval` be GetValue(lref).
> 3. Let `rref` be the result of evaluating `MultiplicativeExpression`.
> 4. Let `rval` be `GetValue(rref)`.
> 5. …

Comment: Good find, I couldn't find this part of the spec to augment my own answer. +1